# Is it impossible to get window scale?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get user activity on a web site. Using JavaScript, I can get window size and mouse position. But when I search on google, I read that it is impossible to get the window scale factor. Is this true? Why can't I get window scale?

The window scale in the given image is 190%.
[image]

Comment: What do you call window scale?

Comment: Hey Kobayashi! Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "window scale" and if possible provide some screenshots explaining your definition? Thanks!